# Selenium-Cucumber can't startup firefox browser when encoding is "UTF-8"

Tags: ruby, firefox, selenium, utf-8, cucumber

When I use Selenium-cucumber to test a website in Firefox, but it can't be work. Selenium-cucumber can't startup Firefox. it will get this message "`invalid byte sequence in UTF-8`".

Because I test a Chinese website, the web code is UTF-8, I changed the encoding for the feature file format, from GBK to UTF-8. 
And add "# encoding: utf-8" in feature file. When I run command line, i still the encoding for the command line format, run "chcp 65001" in the first. 
It will be work done in IE and Chrome browser, but it failed in Firefox. the message is "`invalid byte sequence in UTF-8`".

So I changed the encoding for the command line format, I changed to "chcp 936", it will run command by GBK encoding. and all browser can be run. But the output message in command line about Chinese Characters is garbled.

For solve this problem, i add `string1="#{imagename}".encode('gbk')` and command line encoding is "GBK", it will startup browser successfully and all output text value are right. but it can't be create Junit XML result file. it will get message is "`incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and GBK`".

how should I do to solve this questions to make Selenium-cucumber startup Firefox in encoding "UFT-9" successfully?

Gem List

appium_lib (4.1.0)

cucumber (2.0.2)

cucumber-core (1.2.0)

gherkin (2.12.2 x86-mingw32)

nokogiri (1.6.6.2 x86-mingw32)

selenium-cucumber (2.1.3)

selenium-webdriver (2.45.0)